# Emberjs Inflector for pluralization

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

I have used ember inflector

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.rules.uncountable['quiz'] = true;
var inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector;
inflector.irregular('quiz', 'quizes');

QuizAPP.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});

QuizAPP.QuizShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        console.log("Route of quiz show")
        return this.get('store').find('quiz');
    }
});
```

Expected Outcome in console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/quizes
```

But, Error in console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/quizs 404 (Not Found)
```

Is this correct way of using ember inflector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ember Cli Inflector adjustments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593483/ember-cli-inflector-adjustments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the first line `Ember.Inflector.inflector.rules.uncountable['quiz'] = true;` and it should work. You should not set both an irregular and uncountable rule.

Comment: What version of Ember & Ember Data are you using?

Comment: i was using an earlier version of ember-data, now I have switched to 1.0.0.beta.3. Inflector is working after the upgrdation. Thanks @Roy