# Ember Cli Inflector adjustments

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Where/how can i adjust the [Ember.Inflector](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_pluralization-customization) Class / create an instance of it that ember-cli picks up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I placed it in the model file and it worked fine:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

var inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector;
inflector.irregular('nota', 'notas');
inflector.singular(/nota/, 'nota');

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  language: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks - I'll check that out... But how would that work? We're in no way exporting the Inflector?

Answer (score 10):

I generated an initializer and put this data there.  This ensures it loads before anything that might need it.  Like the model, adapter, or serializer.

initializers/inflector.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export function initialize(/* container, application */) {
  var inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector;
  inflector.uncountable('aamc-pcrs');
}

export default {
  name: 'inflector',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Comment: This is really the way to go. The accepted answer (doing it in the model) will not work for situations like sideloading.

Answer (score 0):

The Ember Guides covers this in [Models - Customizing Adapters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_pluralization-customization):

Create the file `app/models/custom-inflector-rules.js`:

```
import Inflector from 'ember-inflector';

const inflector = Inflector.inflector;

inflector.irregular('formula', 'formulae');
inflector.uncountable('advice');

// Meet Ember Inspector's expectation of an export
export default {};
```

Then in `app/app.js` add the line:

```
import './models/custom-inflector-rules';
```

And if you want to use this in a unit test for a serializer/adapter then you can just import the `custom-inflector-rules` file into the test.